# Number formatting with thousands separator. Indian and international formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format number cells which are for Indian clients in this way - 24,33,000 and for foreign clients like  2,433,000.

I tried these number formatting but my output format varies randomly. Sometimes it is in desired format and sometimes it doesn't. Can you please help. Really appreciate it. Thanks

```
If InvoiceCurr <> "INR" Then
  For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("E15:F29").Cells
    If Not (c.Value = "" Or c.Value = 0) Then
        c.Value = Val(c.Value)
        c.NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0"
    End If
Next c

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").Value)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").NumberFormat = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").Value)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").NumberFormat = "#,##0;-#,##0"
Else
 For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("E15:F29").Cells
    If Not (c.Value = "" Or c.Value = 0) Then
        c.Value = Val(c.Value)
        c.NumberFormat = "#,##,##0"
    End If
Next c

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").Value)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").NumberFormat = Val(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").Value)

'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30") = Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30"), "##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,###.##")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = "#,##,##0"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").NumberFormat = "#,##,##0"
End If
```

Comment: Are you saying that, in India, two million is written as 20,00,000? How is two billion written then? 2,00,00,00,000 or 2,000,000,000?

Comment: Yes 2 million is written as 20,00,000 (twenty lakhs) in India. and this 2,00,00,00,000 is correct as per Indian standard number display.
@Dominique

Comment: So, Indian number notation first groups by thousand, but once you go higher the grouping is done by hundred? Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this the format definition:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = "##\,##\,##0"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").NumberFormat = "##\,##\,##0"
```

and

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = "#\,##0;-#\,##0"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F34").NumberFormat = "#\,##0;-#\,##0"
```

according to the wanted format

Answer (score 0):

For a full implementation in VBA using dynamic formatting, study my article:

[Indian number formatting of Currency in Microsoft Access and Excel](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/35656/Indian-number-formatting-of-Currency-in-Microsoft-Access-and-Excel.html?preview=koDcAVT/uNM%3D)

and code:

```vb
' Format a Currency value in the Indian number format.
'
' Value can be any value between the minimum and maximum of Currency:
'   Value = CCur("-922337203685477.5808")
'   Value = CCur(" 922337203685477.5807")
'
' Example:
'   922337203685477.5807 -> "92,23,37,20,36,85,477.5807"
'
' Digits controls the decimal count:
'   If Digits is less than 0, floating decimals are used.
'   If Digits is between 0 and 4, fixed decimals are used.
'
' Note:
'   For fixed decimals less than four, parameter Value
'   should be rounded before passed to this function.
'
' Source:
'   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system
'
' 2021-01-31. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function FormatIndianCurrency( _
    ByVal Value As Currency, _
    Optional ByVal Digits As Integer = -1) _
    As String

    Const MaxDecimals   As Integer = 4
    
    Dim TextValue       As String

    If Digits < 0 Then
        ' Floating decimal.
        TextValue = _
            Format(Value, ";-") & _
            Format(Abs(Fix(Value)), _
                Right("##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,", _
                ((Len(CStr(Abs(Fix(Value)))) - 2) \ 2) * 4) & _
                "##0") & _
            IIf(Value - Fix(Value), LTrim(Str(Abs(Value - Fix(Value)))), "")
    Else
        ' Fixed decimal.
        If Digits > MaxDecimals Then
            Digits = MaxDecimals
        End If
        TextValue = _
            Format(Value, ";-") & _
            Format(Abs(Fix(Value)), _
                Right("##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,##\,", _
                ((Len(CStr(Abs(Fix(Value)))) - 2) \ 2) * 4) & _
                "##0") & _
            IIf(Value - Fix(Value), _
                Left(LTrim(Str(Abs(Value - Fix(Value)))) & "0000", Sgn(Digits) + Digits), _
                Mid(".0000", 2 - Sgn(Digits), Sgn(Digits) + Digits))
    End If
    
    FormatIndianCurrency = TextValue
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Gustav for your reply.


`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").NumberFormat = FormatIndianCurrency(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").Range("F30").Value)`

After running above line my actual cell value which is 900000999 is now displayed as 990,00,00,999999.

Am I missing something here.

Also My excel format is already in Indian display format. How can I get international formatting of thousands separator. Thanks

Comment: As detailed in the inline comments and the linked article. the function _formats a numeric value_; it is not intended for setting the NumberFormat.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I'll check again.